# Robot Motion Planning using Delaunay and Dijkstra

Tags: computational-geometry, motion-planning

I am trying to develop an algorithm based on delaunay triangulation, fermat point, improved dijkstra's algorithm to implement robot motion planning. Currently I have covered delaunay triangulation and fermat point. I have started my work with Dijkstra's using Fibonacci heap. Currently I am working on polygonal shaped objects. Suppose if I want to include real life curved obstacles, how can I do so? Is there a way to approximate curvy obstacles to polygonal obstacles? Also if a project based on dynamically changing surroundings is to be incorporated, what are the basic ideas required, like what should be covered?

Comment: Of course you can convert curves in polygons.

Comment: Searched in the net a lot, but no specific algorithm on conversion of curved objects to polygonal objects is mentioned. Also the problem I am trying to do is having a goal to achieve complexity of the order of nlgn

Answer (score 1):

You can aproximate a 2d curve, or reduce the number of vertices of a poly line, with the [Douglas-Peucker Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

Comment: Let me try upon it. Thanks for the help